# Should we merge tag [fbconnect] into [facebook]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Since [facebook-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-connect) is a synonym for [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook), I think it makes sense that [fbconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fbconnect) should also be a synonym since they refer to the same thing.

Guidance says:

> fbconnect is an abbreviation for the Facebook Connect sdk which serve as a means to connect to the facebook servers.

---

As requested, I have checked several questions under [fbconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fbconnect). [Sorted by score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fbconnect?tab=Votes). Observations:

- Questions consistently are related to Facebook software development. Unfortunately, I cannot speak to whether they specifically use the Facebook Connect API, but [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) does also cover the usage of software development for Facebook.
- Narrowing the search to [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Votes&pagesize=50&q=%5bfbconnect%5d%20-%5bfacebook%5d%20-%22facebook%22%20is%3aq&searchOn=3) (60 results) that do not explicitly mention "facebook" or tag it, several posts talk about the FBConnect IOS SDK. This is still developing software for Facebook, which the [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) tag technically covers, but I also found the [facebook-ios-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-ios-sdk). Perhaps some clean up here is necessary? Not sure what the best course of action here is.
- Only unrelated posts I found with the narrowed search were:

  - [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3293197), which mistook "fbconnect" for "fbconnection", which is for Firebird.
  - [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5430351/)

Comment: Can you also check and document how the questions currently tagged [[tag:fbconnect]] are actually using that tag in practice? The tag wiki guidance is a good starting point, but we all know that plenty of people don't follow it, so before we merge and synonymize, we want to make sure that theory matches the practice. (If not, some cleanup work may be needed first.)

Comment: @CodyGray Of course.